# Destroy an circular-reference instance in typescript?

Tags: typescript, memory-leaks, circular-reference

Say I have code like following:

```
class A {
    b: B;
    constructor() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B {
    a: A;
    constructor(a: A) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
let a= new A()
```

When I want to destroy instance of a:

**1** Should I just

```
a=null;
```

or

```
a.b.a=null;
a=null;
```

?

**2** Is there any way to write code to test results? Say some code to detect instance number of some class in the memory?

Comment: if there's no reference to a or b it will be marked as unreachable by the garbage collector and be cleaned together, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @toskv So if there is only reference to a, when I use `a=null`. The b will be gc automatically even a and b are circular referenced?

Comment: yep, as long as no one else has a reference to them.

Comment: you can learn more about garbage collection in javascript on the MDN page. keep in mind though that actual implementations may vary. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no reference to a or b it will be marked as unreachable by the garbage collector and be cleaned together, you don't have to do anything manually.

You can find more about how garbage collectors work in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: In the above example, the DOM element "myDivElement" has a circular reference to itself in the "circularReference" property. If the property is not explicitly removed or nulled, a reference-counting garbage collector will always have at least one reference intact and will keep the DOM element in memory even if it was removed from the DOM tree. If the DOM element holds lots of data (illustrated in the above example with the "lotsOfData" property), the memory consumed by this data will never be released.

Comment: That's a quote from the link you sent, are you sure it works like you say? I think the explanation in the docs is vague

Comment: @Esqarrouth No JS engine uses reference counting. Even IE6 and 7 (which are dead since long!) only had problems when DOM objects were involved in the cycle.