# Does Typescript / Javascript garbage collector handle circular references or does it leak memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, siblings, circular-reference

In languages like `C#` this isn't a problem, but this creates hard to find memory bugs in some other languages. Can I use the following code in `Typescript` or `Javascript` and trust that everything will be fine?

```
class Dad {
    kids: Kid[];
}
class Kid {
    dad: Dad;
    siblings: Kid[];
}

let anakin: Dad | undefined;

function makeKids(dad: Dad) {
    const luke = new Kid();
    const leia = new Kid();
    luke.dad = dad;
    leia.dad = dad;
    luke.siblings = [leia];
    leia.siblings = [luke];
    dad.kids = [luke, leia];
}

anakin = new Dad();
makeKids(anakin);
console.log(anakin.kids.length); // Prints out 2
anakin = undefined;
// I expect luke and leia to die at this point
// Not float around the memory space infinitely
```

Or should I make the variable kids and siblings optional and add a `destructor`? Something like this:

```
kids?: Kid[];
siblings?: Kid[];
destructor() {
    this.kids = undefined
}
```

Here is a related topic and I wasn't satisfied with the answer: [Destroy an circular-reference instance in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819466/destroy-an-circular-reference-instance-in-typescript)

Comment: What's the specific issue? IIRC pretty much everything current has at least mark-and-sweep GC, which makes memory leaks due to circular references unlikely, although I suppose not impossible (although I'm having a hard time coming up w/ scenarios).

Comment: There are no destructors in JS. You would have to call them manually.

Comment: @Bergi yes, that is what I meant by `add destructor`.

Comment: @DaveNewton issue is exactly like this. But 50x larger classes and different names. I'm holding an dad object, which his holding a kid object. At some point I'm removing the dad object from the array it is in. And I am hoping the kid object will die.

Comment: @DaveNewton edited the example code a little bit more

Comment: @Esqarrouth The number of objects isn't really relevant, though; the mechanism is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a runtime.

There are many JavaScript runtimes, so it's impossible to say some particular thing is true of *all* of them, but all the major runtimes (those shipped in popular browsers, node.js) are easily capable of dealing with disconnected circular references.

There is a well-defined memory root in JS from which it's easy to do a mark-and-sweep GC, which has no problems dealing with circular references. Circular references are really only an issue in ref-counted GC systems and there's no great reason to do ref counting in the JS language since you don't need deterministic cleanup.